# Questions about Frank Tipler's Omega Point theory?

Tags: quantum-physics, cosmology, universe

He defends in that theory that God could become real, but that he would be limited. He wouldn't be strictly the same God as the one in classical religion. He couldn't do/know the physically and logically impossible (He would neither be able to know the Cantgotu environments, which is physically impossible, nor he would know illogical concepts..etc) In this page (http://thedebriefing.net/articles/book-reviews/physics-christianity/), it says that "Tipler points out that though quantum unitarity is a strong from of determinism, it is possible for free will to co-exist. The muliverse is subject to the quantum identity theory. According to Tipler, God cannot know or do what it is logically impossible to know or do. Before an analogue of any individual makes a decision or does something he or she is that same as all other analogues in all universes of the multiverse down to a quantum level. Physics only permit knowledge of a certain likelihood of a particular thought or act (“a percentage“). This is despite the argument that though we are unaware of all our analogues, God is aware via the Second Hypostasis of the Singularity."

My doubt is what does it mean with "Physics only permit knowledge of a certain likelihood of a particular thought or act (“a percentage“)"? Would this happen also at the final singularity of Omega Point Theory? If yes, why? If infinite information is generated near the final moment of the Omega Point "singularity", wouldn't it be able to have a "100%" certain (not only a likelihood) knowledge about a thought or act?

Comment: I have doubts about the Tiplers theory. Its been [described](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_J._Tipler#The_Omega_Point_cosmology) by the philosopher Rem B. Edwards as "futuristic, pseudoscientific eschatology" that is "highly conjectural, unverified, and improbable" and by the cosmologist, George Ellis  "a masterpiece of pseudoscience… the product of a fertile and creative imagination unhampered by the normal constraints of scientific and philosophical discipline" ...

Comment: ...and by the physicist Lawrence Krauss " "extreme example of uncritical and unsubstantiated arguments put into print by an intelligent professional scientist"; he might have done better by publishing it as science fiction to investigate such speculative ideas as have Isaac Asimov & Olaf Stapledon.

Comment: I do not see this theory as a probable option either. What is interesting is that as the theory says, if infinite information was created at the final moments of the universe, then the final Omega Point entity should be at least omniscient.

Comment: I had a conversation with David Deutsch who criticised the theory for making exaggerated religious claims (the entity of the omega point theory wouldn't have god-like omniscience capable of knowing/thinking the physically and logically impossible to think: capable of knowing Cantgotu environments, illogical concepts...etc). Because i wanted an answer from a physical (not "mystical" or religious) point of view, i asked him the same question. He told me, that if that amount of info was infinite it wouldn't necessarily mean that it was info about everything, so it wouldn't be omniscient.

Comment: Then my final and true question (that I'd like to be answered here) is: If the situation above occurred and the created info was about everything, then the phrase "Physics only permit knowledge of a certain likelihood of a particular thought or act (“a percentage“)" wouldn't apply there? If physics didn't change, then what could change that in that situation? @MoziburUllah

Comment: To me it seems like a lot of hypotheticals on top of other hypotheticals - so I can't really comment on the specifics;  my main comment is that its essentially Hegels Phenomenology/Logic put into speculative physical terms.

Comment: I know, but assuming these hypotheses were true, then what happens with "Physics only permit knowledge of a certain likelihood of a particular thought or act (“a percentage“)" @MoziburUllah

Comment: Well, I'd say its too many ifs for physics proper.

Comment: at least do you know if "Physics only permit knowledge of a certain likelihood of a particular thought or act (“a percentage“)" always apply? Are there situations where it does not apply? Could the final moments of the omega point theory (if info about *everything* was created) be one of them? @MoziburUllah

Comment: It appears to be an incoherent statement: If you have a thought, I can ask you, and you can tell me (or not). Physics has nothing to do with it. I'd also say that its not a matter of knowing - as it is in physics - but a matter of judging; and personally speaking, in judging this, I'm in agreement with the physicists above.

Comment: I think it's referring to probability. But there can be situations where a probability transforms into 100% certain thing. If the omega point would know everything, would this happen then? @MoziburUllah

Comment: Probability is not a method that one can apply to speculative thought. A 100% probability=certainty, but that's as far as it goes - so I don't understand your second sentence. As for your third sentence, I've already said enough about this.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Well, if someone is looking to an apple, probably he's thinking about that apple. Or maybe he/she's thinking about something else. We don't know, but we can say what thoughts are more probable. If somehow we could read the mind of the subject, we will "transform" those probabilities into 100% sure things isn't it? (e.g. The subject it's certainly thinking about the apple and not thinking about any other thing)

Comment: Sure, probable is distinct from probability - with probability the idea is that we fix a number to it; its this that I have a problem with here.

Comment: "Tipler points out that though quantum unitarity is a strong from of determinism, it is possible for free will to co-exist. The muliverse is subject to the quantum identity theory. According to Tipler, God cannot know or do what it is logically impossible to know or do. Before an analogue of any individual makes a decision or does something he or she is that same as all other analogues in all universes of the multiverse down to a quantum level. Physics only permit knowledge of a certain likelihood of a particular thought or act (“a percentage“)."

Comment: maybe you can deduce from here what it's referring to then @MoziburUllah

Comment: I'm not interested in multiverses - this universe is enough for me.

Comment: What part of 'pseudo-science' don't you understand? Its not my word, its by George Ellis - he who wrote a book on cosmology with Stephen Hawking. There's little point in deductions in such a framework - all one can do is admire or laugh at it.

Comment: +1 I agree with Mozibur Ullah's comments, but I would like to get more clarity about many worlds, whether it comes from Tipler or Deutsche.  I don't think many worlds is a valid interpretation of QM, but I don't know how to argue against it.

Comment: @FrankHubeny Deutsch has two books "The Fabric of Reality" and "The Beginning of Infinity" that you could read. I am familiar with Deutsch's position would also be willing to answer questions by e-mail alanmichaelforrester@googlemail.com. You could also e-mail Deutsch and he might reply.

Comment: @alanf I missed your earlier comment. Thank you for the offer. I don't have any specific questions at the moment. I have read Deutsch's book some years ago, but it did not convince me.  One could have quantum reality acting as limited agents making choices within constraints. It is a simpler solution to randomness or many worlds. It also fits Conway and Kochen's free will theorem.

Comment: Tipler ignores the argument from probability; assuming an infinitely-causal chain in the past, then it's likely for a mind exist somewhere along than causal-chain. Said mind would have total power over the events it causes such as us.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is pseudoscience. If it was intended as science, its probably science. Certainly science has been known to be wrong... so maybe its wrong.

But it doesn't seem wrong. If anything, it seems emotionally charged since he ties in religion. But then rather than he being non-scientific, I think the real issue is how  does one scientifically critique him?

Probably the easiest way is to judge the math and also observe the world to see if things are more or less consistent, if you adopt his framework.

I read an interesting statement today that said QM equations would only be consistent if what Frank Tipler proposed were true. As I was looking into, I came on this interesting thread and had three things to contribute:

1. If Frank Tipler were objectively wrong (i.e. screwed up the math), we
   could do much less than admire or laugh at it. We, nor anyone, would
   still be talking or thinking about it.
2. "Physics only permits knowledge of a certain likelihood of a certain
   act/thought" -- Please read: Phys Rev Lett. 2011 Jan
   28;106(4):040403. The past has to be consistent and maybe imposed
   through an interesting idea of post-seletion. QM might back-warp the
   universe of probabilities to make an observable, consistent past
   happen in forward time. (i.e. next time I look at an apple, I'll
   probably be thinking more about this than the apple (and even more
   so now that its written)).
3. Logical/Illogical - I think there are mathematical statements that are
       illogical, but still true. There have been many systems of logic. If
       the past is any indication, then there will probably be a more
       before a theoretical Omega Point. I think is probably best to wait
       humbly until we get closer to get a better idea of what logic looks
       like then.

For now, I'll throw my dice in for omniscience, since this seems the most logical! But will cede to Alan F. whom I'm pretty sure knows the real deal.

Comment: "If it was intended as science, its probably science." Every pseudoscience was intended as science from their creators' views.